# Issues with Fourier transform in M.12.1.0

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I am using M. Version: 12.1.0. In version 10, I got the result right away.So, Why mathematica (12.1.0) is not able to solve this problem?

```
   ff = ((4 \[Pi])/r) 1/(8 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(5/2))
       FourierSinTransform[-((Sin[a k]^2)/(a^2 (k^2 + 1))), k, r, 
       Assumptions -> {a > 0, r < 2 a}]
```

It gave me

```
FourierSinTransform[-(Sin[a k]^2/(a^2 (1 + k^2))), k, r, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, r < 2 a}]/(2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2) r)
```

Comment: @Nasser Imm! Idid know what to do.

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. Now when I run the notebook the Mathematica crashes and turnoff the notebook.

Comment: @Nasser might be. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac it works but very slowly.

```
$Version

(* "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

AbsoluteTiming[
 ff = Assuming[{a > 0, r < 2 a},
   ((4 π)/r) 1/(8 Sqrt[2] π^(5/2))*
     FourierSinTransform[
      -((Sin[a k]^2)/(a^2 (k^2 + 1))), k, r] //
    Simplify]]

(* {105.652, (1/(
 16 a^2 π^2 r))(-I π Sinh[2 a - r] + 
   2 CosIntegral[I (2 a - r)] Sinh[2 a - r] - 2 I π Sinh[r] + 
   4 CosIntegral[I r] Sinh[r] + I π Sinh[2 a + r] - 
   2 CosIntegral[I (2 a + r)] Sinh[2 a + r] - 
   2 Cosh[2 a - r] SinhIntegral[2 a - r] - 4 Cosh[r] SinhIntegral[r] + 
   2 Cosh[2 a + r] SinhIntegral[2 a + r])} *)

ff /. {a -> 2.0`20, r -> 1.0`20} // Chop

(* -0.00459509964094965 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can speed up:

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];
$Version
(*"12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)"*)

SOL = (1/(2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2) r)*
  LaplaceTransform[
   FourierSinTransform[
     InverseLaplaceTransform[-(Sin[a k]^2/(a^2 (B + k^2))), B, s],
      k, r, Assumptions -> {a > 0, r < 2 a, s > 0}] // Expand, s, 
   B, Assumptions -> {a > 0, r < 2 a}] /. B -> 1 // Expand) // 
 AbsoluteTiming

 (*{13.0442, -(MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, r^2/4]/(8 a^2 \[Pi]^(3/2) r)) - 
               MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 1/4 (-2 a + r)^2]/(16 a^2 \[Pi]^(3/2) r) + 
               MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, 1/4 (2 a + r)^2]/(16 a^2 \[Pi]^(3/2) r)}*)

 N[SOL[[2]] /. {a -> 2, r -> 1}, 20]
 (*-0.0045950996409496493638*)
```

Comment: +1 Recommend that you use parentheses to isolate definitions from wrappers, e.g., `(SOL = ...) // AbsoluteTiming` and then `(SOL2 = SOL // FunctionExpand // Simplify[#, {a > 0, r < 2 a}]&) // AbsoluteTiming` will give a form like the direct approach.