# Problem with Fourier Transform output

Tags: equation-solving, fourier-analysis

I am trying to evaluate this FT, but Mathematica takes long time without output

```
FourierSinTransform[-((k Sin[a k]^2)/((k^2 + B^2))), k, r, FourierParameters -> {0, 1}]
```

Comment: General hint and recommendation:  Eliminate all useless factors.  Do you need to call this `ft`?  Of course not; delete it.  Do you need the constant in front?  Of course not; delete it.  Do you need `a^2 B^2 \[Epsilon]`?  Of course not; call it `q`.  And so on.  This may solve your problem directly, but it will also focus on the *core* problem, and garner more help.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I did all your recommendation, but no solution yet.

Comment: If you make such changes, go back and fix the posted problem!  The point of simplifying is to help *US* help you too.

Comment: Sorry to harp on this, but I'm hoping this is a "teachable moment."  Do you see why the `ft` is useless, as I pointed out before? 
 Why keep it??? Do you see why you don't have to define q?  Who cares that it is `a^2 B^2 \[Epsilon]`?  And who cares that $B >0$?  It always appears as $B^2$ in the function.  I urge you to take this chance and push further for a "minimum working example."  You can do it!!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork no need for `q`, but does it matter for Mathematica?!!

Comment: You *still* have the useless `ft =`!!  And who needs the minus sign?  Or the `A`??  Even some of the parentheses are extraneous!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry, but I did not see why I need to change ft?

Comment: To *SIMPLIFY* everything.  Make it easier to read, easier to search.  Try to give even one good reason to *keep* it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: form [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219288/issues-with-fourier-transform-in-m-12-1-0/219318#219318) we have:

```
 SOL = (LaplaceTransform[
  FourierSinTransform[
    InverseLaplaceTransform[-((k Sin[a k]^2)/(A*B^2 + k^2)), A, 
     s], k, r, Assumptions -> {a > 0, s > 0, B > 0}, 
    FourierParameters -> {0, 1}] // Expand, s, A, 
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, B > 0}] /. A -> 1 // FullSimplify) // 
AbsoluteTiming

(*{25.6463, 
1/4 Sqrt[\[Pi]/
2] (-2 E^(-(B/Sqrt[(1/r^2)])) Sqrt[1/r^2] r + 
E^(-(B/Sqrt[(1/(-2 a + r)^2)])) Sqrt[1/(-2 a + r)^2] (-2 a + r) + 
E^(-(B/Sqrt[(1/(2 a + r)^2)])) Sqrt[1/(2 a + r)^2] (2 a + r))}*)

FullSimplify[SOL[[2]] // ExpToTrig, Assumptions -> {B > 0, r > 0, a > 0}]

(*1/4 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] (-2 E^(-B r) + E^(-B (2 a + r)) + (E^(-B Abs[-2 a + r]) (-2 a + r))/Abs[-2 a + r])*)
```

To get **Not** complicated solution:

$$\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\frac{(r-2 a) e^{-B | r-2 a| }}{| r-2 a| }+e^{-B (2 a+r)}-2 e^{-B r}\right)$$

Comment: +1. The command InverseFourierSinTransform[
 1/4 Sqrt[\ [Pi]/2] (-2 E^(-B * r) + 
    E^(-B *  (2 a + r)) + (E^(-B  * RealAbs[-2 a + r]) (-2 a + r))/
     RealAbs[-2 a + r]), r, k, FourierParameters -> {0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, B > 0}] produces $$-\frac{k \sin ^2(a k)}{B^2+k^2}.
    $$

Comment: Mariusz Iwaniuk, Could you explain the idea behind using `LaplaceTransform`?

Comment: @user68344.  You have to analyze the code yourself, because I do not know how to explain it to you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is even and a Fourier sine transform reveals non-zero terms only for odd functions.

I realized this once I eliminated all the useless and distracting terms in the question:

[image]

I suspect, though, that this form does not have a closed-form solution even for an even (cosine) transform.

When you pare down all the useless constants, definitions, equation names, and so on, the code reduces to:

```
FourierSinTransform[k Sin[a k]^2/(k^2 + t), k, r,
 FourierParameters -> {0, 1}]
```

which indeed takes too long.

So let's follow Dr. Fourier and work with a *full* Fourier transform.  Then we get the solution:

```
FullSimplify[
 FourierTransform[k Sin[a k]^2/(k^2 + t), k, r]
]
```

An extremely complicated solution:

$$-\frac{i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (2 a-r) e^{\sqrt{t} (r-2 a)}}{4 \sqrt{t}}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (r-2 a) e^{\sqrt{t} (2 a-r)}}{4 \sqrt{t}}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (2 a+r) e^{\sqrt{t} (-(2 a+r))}}{4 \sqrt{t}}-\frac{i
   \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \delta (2 a+r) e^{\sqrt{t} (2 a+r)}}{4 \sqrt{t}}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\sqrt{t} (-(2 a+r))} \left(2 \sqrt{t} \theta (-2 a-r) e^{2
   \sqrt{t} (2 a+r)}+2 \sqrt{t} e^{2 r \sqrt{t}} \theta (2 a-r)-4 \sqrt{t} \theta (-r)
   e^{2 \sqrt{t} (a+r)}+4 \sqrt{t} e^{2 a \sqrt{t}} \theta (r)-2 \sqrt{t} e^{4 a
   \sqrt{t}} \theta (r-2 a)-2 \sqrt{t} \theta (2 a+r)+e^{4 a \sqrt{t}} \text{sgn}'(2
   a-r)-e^{4 a \sqrt{t}} \text{sgn}'(r-2 a)\right)}{8 \sqrt{t}}$$

You can take the Real and Imaginary parts of this to get your Sin transform.

Comment: What does $\text{sgn}'(r-2 a)$ mean? TIA.

Comment: The outputs of FourierTransform[-((k Sin[a k]^2)/((k^2 + t))), k, r, 
 FourierParameters -> {0, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && t > 0]  and FourierTransform[-((k Sin[a k]^2)/((k^2 + t))), k, r, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0 && t > 0] differ from yours.

Comment: You write the function is even, but it is odd..

Comment: Another point, in the comment above you write "Who cares if $B>0$". If not, all these square roots $\sqrt{t}$ pop up, also not very insightful.

Comment: @yarchik.  No, not quite.  In the original posting every occurrence of $B$ was as $B^2$, so I reconfirm my statement/question:  "Who cares if $B$ is negative?"

Comment: @David G. Stork: I am somewhat troubled by no reply of you. I believe civilized people use to answer requests.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done for specific values of $a,B$. The reason it can not be done otherwise, is due to difficulty finding the limit at $\infty$ for general $a,B$.

The function you are trying to find its `FourierSinTransform` is just

$$
\frac{k \sin ^2(a k)}{B^2+k^2}
$$

Everything else is not needed. Using Wolfram definition of [FourierSinTransform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSinTransform.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where $t$ is your $k$.

```
ClearAll[f, B, a, k, r];
f[0] = (k Sin[a k]^2)/(k^2 + B^2)
```

Lets look at your function first, for say $a=2,B=4$. It shows it is odd function:

```
 Plot[f[0] /. {a -> 2, B -> 4}, {k, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we apply definition of `FourierSinTransform`. But I had to use `Rubi` to get anti derivative which was simpler that `Integrate` and allowed `Limit` to be taken, otherwise, `Limit` would hang. At least I waited too long to find out.

```
 << Rubi`
 f[1] = Int[f[0]*Sin[k r], k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Limit[f[1], k -> 0]
 (*0*)
```

And

```
Limit[(f[1] /. {a -> 1, B -> 2})*UnitStep[k], k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> r < 2 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[(f[1] /. {a -> 2, B -> 4})*UnitStep[k], k -> Infinity, Assumptions -> r < 4
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using direct `FourierSinTransform` it hangs

```
FourierSinTransform[f[0] /. {a -> 1, B -> 2}, k, r, Assumptions -> r < 2]
```

Comment: BTW, up to the documentation  (see Details and Options in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSinTransform.html  ),"Other definitions are used in some scientific and technical fields".